QEMU vnc + opengl via virtio-vga-gl does not work, how to make it work or why does it not work?
In short, my question might be what's the configure options and/or the qemu-system-x86_64 command line options to run QEMU heedlessly with the virgl 3D feature turned on. By virgl 3D, I meant something like -device virtio-vga-gl or -device virtio-gpu-gl; I believe that the user space software would rely on the virtio-gpu driver and the driver effectively sends the gpu commands to libvirglrenderer on the host. Here are more details/contexts.
If vnc and virgl 3D is not to work together, what would be the reasons? I am aware of another virtual machine implementation where something like virgl 3D works with a headless VM instance.
I am trying to run QEMU with -device virtio-vga-gl and test a OpenGL benchmark on it. The host and guest are both Linux: Debian 11 and Ubuntu 24. I tried the following commands:
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -bios /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd  -m 16G -M q35 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 2  -hda ./ubuntu.qcow2 -device virtio-vga-gl -display vnc=:2
qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-vga-gl: opengl is not available

$ $ qemu-system-x86_64 -bios /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd  -m 16G -M q35 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 2 -hda ./ubuntu.qcow2 -device virtio-vga-gl -display vnc=:2,gl=on
qemu-system-x86_64: -display vnc=:2,gl=on: Invalid parameter 'gl'

The QEMU version is 9.0 and built with the following configure options:
./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-opengl --enable-sdl --enable-gtk --enable-kvm --enable-guest-agent --enable-spice --enable-virglrenderer --enable-vnc --audio-drv-list="alsa, default" --enable-libusb --prefix=/usr/local

Is vnc display particularly not supposed to work with so called virgl 3D? I tried it with -display sdl,gl=on, which rendered graphics for me. However, when running an OpenGL benchmark, it was slower than, I guess, the software 3D rendering. I think it might be because raw frame buffers are created in the guest when it's virgl 3D (i.e. forwarding the device driver commands of virtio-gpu to virglrenderer on the host) and copied to whatever UI coupled with the sdl display. To test my theory, I wanted to run QEMU in a headless mode and thought it's VNC. And, I failed to get QEMU to work with both vnc and virgl 3D.
